# Maintain only link with specific string and extension in curl

Tags: curl, awk, grep

I try to obtain all links on a webpage using this command:

`curl https://www.theiphonewiki.com/wiki/Firmware/iPhone/11.x 2>&1 | grep -o -E 'href="([^"#]+)"' | cut -d'"' -f2`

Sample output from the above command:

```
/w/index.php?title=1.62.00&amp;action=edit&amp;redlink=1
/w/index.php?title=1.03.06&amp;action=edit&amp;redlink=1
http://appldnld.apple.com/ios11.2/091-50808-20171204-1847CB08-D51D-11E7-881F-9E4D7B7A613A/iPhone10,6_11.2_15C113_Restore.ipsw
/w/index.php?title=Cinar_15C114_(iPhone10,3)&amp;action=edit&amp;redlink=1
/w/index.php?title=Cinar_15C114_(iPhone10,6)&amp;action=edit&amp;redlink=1
http://appldnld.apple.com/ios11.2/091-51760-20171206-BA09FB16-D5F7-11E7-A344-36B9DC24E03F/iPhone10,6_11.2_15C114_Restore.ipsw
http://appldnld.apple.com/ios11.2/091-48448-20171204-6BBD49C4-BB37-457E-B21F-D3758FAFC4BC/iPhoneiTunesUpdateReadMe.ipd
/w/index.php?title=Cinar_15C153_(iPhone10,3)&amp;action=edit&amp;redlink=1
/w/index.php?title=Cinar_15C153_(iPhone10,6)&amp;action=edit&amp;redlink=1
http://appldnld.apple.com/ios11.2.1/091-54847-20171213-5FBB02FC-DDFB-11E7-9CEF-07E4FB2783B2/iPhone10,6_11.2.1_15C153_Restore.ipsw
http://appldnld.apple.com/ios11.2.1/091-56152-20171213-AC5CB9A6-DF73-11E7-99DE-5B0F1E4B8CED/iPhoneiTunesUpdateReadMe.ipd
/w/index.php?title=Cinar_15C202_(iPhone10,3)&amp;action=edit&amp;redlink=1
/w/index.php?title=Cinar_15C202_(iPhone10,6)&amp;action=edit&amp;redlink=1
http://appldnld.apple.com/ios11.2.2/091-58675-20170108-B84E4534-F0C8-11E7-B3D8-7C2D869EB6BD/iPhone10,6_11.2.2_15C202_Restore.ipsw
http://appldnld.apple.com/ios11.2.2/091-58073-20180108-92DAC272-EFDE-11E7-83F1-982A165C2DF1/iPhoneiTunesUpdateReadMe.ipd
```

From here I wanted to only keep the link contains the word `iPhone10,6` and end with extension `.ipsw`. Any help how do I proceed from that command line?

Expected output would be:

```
http://appldnld.apple.com/ios11.2/091-50808-20171204-1847CB08-D51D-11E7-881F-9E4D7B7A613A/iPhone10,6_11.2_15C113_Restore.ipsw
http://appldnld.apple.com/ios11.2/091-51760-20171206-BA09FB16-D5F7-11E7-A344-36B9DC24E03F/iPhone10,6_11.2_15C114_Restore.ipsw
http://appldnld.apple.com/ios11.2.1/091-54847-20171213-5FBB02FC-DDFB-11E7-9CEF-07E4FB2783B2/iPhone10,6_11.2.1_15C153_Restore.ipsw
http://appldnld.apple.com/ios11.2.2/091-58675-20170108-B84E4534-F0C8-11E7-B3D8-7C2D869EB6BD/iPhone10,6_11.2.2_15C202_Restore.ipsw
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the output of the `curl` command to the question? and show the exact output you need

Comment: Sorry, edited the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simplify the bunch of `grep` and `cut` with one simple `awk`, but it is outside the context of the question. But for your requirement though, just pipe the output to `AWK` as

```
| awk '/(iPhone10,6)/ && /.ipsw$/'
```

which defines two regex conditions to match `(iPhone10,6)` and to end with `.ipsw` extension.

As promised to do the whole thing in `awk` itself, we can use the `gensub()` function in GNU `awk` to capture the string with `href` and once the URL is identified print it if it matches the string needed using `match()` function

```
curl ... | awk '{url=gensub(/^(.*)href="([^"#]+)"(.*)$/,"\\2","g",$0); if (match(url, /iPhone10,6.*\.ipsw/)) print url}'
```

Comment: That's awesome. Can't believe it's simple as that! If you don't mind, how would one imply the `grep` and `cut` with  one `awk`. I'm eager to learn :)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the accepted answer, you could replace `grep` - `cut` combinations with `awk`. But `sed` too could be used. Here is how it goes for this problem :

**Script**

```
# curl https://www.theiphonewiki.com/wiki/Firmware/iPhone/11.x 2>&1 |
 sed -nE '/iPhone10,6.*\.ipsw/{s/^.*href="([^"#]+)".*$/\1/p}'
```

**Output**

```
http://appldnld.apple.com/ios11.1seed/091-41194-20171023-8AEAD654-B5F2-11E7-8655-C76EBEA7E146/iPhone10,6_11.1_15B93_Restore.ipsw
http://appldnld.apple.com/ios11.1.1/091-42552-20171106-4525806E-C39A-11E7-B432-4BBCF8FD2868/iPhone10,6_11.1.1_15B150_Restore.ipsw
http://appldnld.apple.com/ios11.1.2/091-48137-20171116-4F9256F2-C9C7-11E7-8F92-8DE0F451CBCD/iPhone10,6_11.1.2_15B202_Restore.ipsw
http://appldnld.apple.com/ios11.2/091-50808-20171204-1847CB08-D51D-11E7-881F-9E4D7B7A613A/iPhone10,6_11.2_15C113_Restore.ipsw
http://appldnld.apple.com/ios11.2/091-51760-20171206-BA09FB16-D5F7-11E7-A344-36B9DC24E03F/iPhone10,6_11.2_15C114_Restore.ipsw
http://appldnld.apple.com/ios11.2.1/091-54847-20171213-5FBB02FC-DDFB-11E7-9CEF-07E4FB2783B2/iPhone10,6_11.2.1_15C153_Restore.ipsw
http://appldnld.apple.com/ios11.2.2/091-58675-20170108-B84E4534-F0C8-11E7-B3D8-7C2D869EB6BD/iPhone10,6_11.2.2_15C202_Restore.ipsw
```

---

<sup>**Note**: This is ***significantly*** faster than the actual approach.</sup>